# Invisible Delete button of my listview from all rows in android

Tags: android, button, android-listview, visibility

I am trying to show and hide a delete button in each row of my ListView using a button click.

For this, I tried using the code below:

```
SavedHomeBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        Context cntx;
        public SavedHomeBaseAdapter(Context context) {          
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return m_savedHomesList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public View getView( final int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.nearbyhomestext, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.sqrt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_squareft);
                holder.fromPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_from_price);
                holder.deleteButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }   

            } 
                  if(MyActivity.editButtonState)
            {
                holder.deleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                MyActivity.editButtonState =false;
            }


            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Here, if editButtonState is true.. then the first row's delete button is Hided. But, I want to hide the delete button of all items from the list view.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hide (make `invisible`, `gone`) the `listviews` maybe (I think it's the ViewHolder)?

Comment: then you should avoid to keep a static field for all the buttons

Comment: @blackbelt: can you please explain more.

Comment: if editButtonState is true you want all the delete buttons invisible?

Comment: yes, I need to invisible only delete button from all the ListView rows.But, currently my code hides delete button from first row only..

Comment: you said that you have hide buttons after button click...so which button click????

Comment: No.. here I passed the Boolean value from my button click, which is exists inside of  my activity's header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing this two lines?

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
MyActivity.editButtonState =false;
```

I mean, if you want to hide all buttons, dont change `editButtonState` value there because the next time your code goes through the method the value will be false, so the other elements won't be hidded.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I misunderstood the need for a loop, or, no need in actual fact, as you said. I see now that getView is for individual items.

You may also want to move this code:

MyActivity.editButtonState =false;

to the code block underneath the button you press to show/hide. At the moment, it will execute after the first row is hidden, therefore meaning

```
if(MyActivity.editButtonState)
```

won't get called more than once. Put it under the show/hide button, at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your replay..Why I need to use loop? Here I called the adapter and invisible the Delete Button using Holder..